# How to map the nested data in a document from Firestore by Swift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document data structure on Firestore like this:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1cZM.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JN2D.png)
So there are 2 map-objects inside the document and a collection and a another document inside this document

Then I create 3 model swift files for this document

**task:**

```
struct task {
    var Name: String
    var Address: String
    var Car: CarModel
    car Price: PriceModel

    var dictionary: [String:Any] {
        return [
            "Name" : Name,
            "Address" : Address,
            "Car" : CarModel,
            "Price" : PriceModel
        ]
    }

    init?(data: [String:Any]) {
        guard let Name = dictionary["Name"] as? String,
            let Address = dictionary["Address"] as? String,
            let Car = ditionary["car"] as? CarModel,
            let Price = dictionary["price"] as? PriceModel else{
            return nil
        }
        self.Name = Name
        self.Address = Address
        self.Car = Car
        self.Price = Price
    }
}
```

**CarModel**:

```
struct CarModel {
    var brand: String
    var model: String
    var year: String


    var dictionary: [String:Any] {
        return [
            "brand" : brand,
            "model" : model,
            "year" : year,
        ]
    }

    init?(data: [String:Any]) {
        guard let brand = dictionary["brand"] as? String,
            let model = dictionary["model"] as? String,
            let year = ditionary["year"] as? String else{
            return nil
        }
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    }
}
```

**PriceModel:**

```
struct PriceModel {
    var basic: Int
    var extra: Int


    var dictionary: [String:Any] {
        return [
            "basic" : basic,
            "extra" : extra,
        ]
    }

    init?(data: [String:Any]) {
        guard let basic = dictionary["basic"] as? Int,
            let extra = ditionary["extra"] as? Int else{
            return nil
        }
        self.basic = basic
        self.extra = extra
    }
}
```

Then download the data with this following code:

```
func loadDataFromFirestore(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        var success: Bool = false

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
            let colRef = db.collection("tasks")
            downloadGroup.enter()
            colRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                for document in querySnapshot!.documents{
                    let result = document.data()
                    print (result)
                    if let data = task(data: result){
                        print(data)
                    }
                }
                success = true

                downloadGroup.leave()
            }
            downloadGroup.wait()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(success)
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get the data with comment the CarModel and PriceModel, but if I uncomment these two, it will let my app crash!
So how could I get the map-object to adapt to my code?
And the second question is: How can I get the document inside a document's collection with this kind of code?

Comment: So to understand better, you can get the objects of type `CarModel` and `PriceModel` but you cannot get the `task` object which contains two string fields and one `CarModel` and `PriceModel` fields, right?